# Getting a segmentation Fault when attempting to access function

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I believe the segmentation fault is happening at my If statement but im unsure why that is, when using the test it doesnt even seem to get through into the If statement when testing if `knapsack == NULL`it doesnt even go to the next printf statement. Can i not test knapsack for being equal to NULL even though my main passes NULL into knapsack? Only Knapsack.c can be edited as per specifications. Knapsack.h and Knapsack-testcase1.c were given to me and were SPECIFICALLY told not to be edited.

**Knapsack.h**

```
/* knapsack.h
 * implements simple knapsack data structure as a linked list 
 * NOTE: a function may update the value of input argument *knapsack if it changes the first node of the knapsack to another node. Such a change include the case when an item is added to an empty knapsack
 */

typedef struct listitem* listitemptr;

struct listitem {
  int item;           // actual int item
  unsigned int count; // number of the same item in the knapsack; should be >= 1
  listitemptr next;   // pointer to next item 
};

listitemptr KnapsackAdd(listitemptr *knapsack, int item);    
int KnapsackRemove(listitemptr *knapsack, int item);
void KnapsackPrint(const listitemptr *knapsack);
unsigned int KnapsackItemCount(const listitemptr *knapsack, int item);
unsigned int KnapsackSize(const listitemptr *knapsack);
```

**Knapsack.c**

```
#include "knapsack.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

listitemptr KnapsackAdd(listitemptr *knapsack, int item){
   if(*knapsack==NULL){//empty list
       listitemptr newest= (listitemptr) malloc(sizeof(struct listitem));
       newest->item=item;
       newest->count=1;
       newest->next=NULL;
       return newest;
   }else{
       listitemptr temp=*knapsack;
       listitemptr previous=NULL;
       while(temp!=NULL){
           if(temp->item == item){
               temp->count=temp->count+1;
               break;
           }
           previous=temp;
           temp=temp->next;
       }
       if(temp==NULL){
           listitemptr newest= (listitemptr) malloc(sizeof(struct listitem));
           newest->item=item;
           newest->count=1;
           newest->next=NULL;
           previous->next=newest;
           return newest;
       }
       return temp;
   }
}

int KnapsackRemove(listitemptr *knapsack, int item){
   if(*knapsack==NULL)
       return -1;
   listitemptr present=*knapsack;
   listitemptr previous=NULL;

   while(present!=NULL){
       if(present->item==item){
           if(present->count>1){
               present->count=present->count-1;
           }else{
               if(previous==NULL){ //delete at head
                   *knapsack=present->next;
               }else{
                   previous->next=present->next;
                   free(present);
               }
           }
           break;
       }
       previous=present;
       present=present->next;
   }

   return 0;
}

void KnapsackPrint(const listitemptr *knapsack){
   if(*knapsack==NULL)
       printf("(nothing)\n");
   else{
       listitemptr temp=*knapsack;
       while(temp!=NULL){
           printf("%d (%d), ",temp->item,temp->count);
           temp=temp->next;
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
}

unsigned int KnapsackItemCount(const listitemptr *knapsack, int item){
   if(*knapsack==NULL)
       return 0;
   listitemptr temp=*knapsack;
   while(temp!=NULL){
       if(temp->item==item)
           return temp->count;
       temp=temp->next;
   }
   return 0;  
}

unsigned int KnapsackSize(const listitemptr *knapsack){
    printf("saada\n");
   if(*knapsack==NULL){
    printf("testing\n");
       return 0;
   }

   listitemptr temp=*knapsack;
   unsigned int sum=0;
   while(temp!=NULL){
       sum+=temp->count;
       temp=temp->next;
   }
   return sum;
```

**Knapsack-testcase1.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include "knapsack.h"

int main(int argc, char* *argv){
    listitemptr k1 = NULL;
    int returnval;

    printf("Test case 1\n");

    printf("Asserting empty knapsack has size 0\n");
    returnval = KnapsackSize(&k1);
    assert(returnval == 0);

    KnapsackAdd(&k1, 1);
    printf("Asserting knapsack with one item (count 1) has size 1\n");
    returnval = KnapsackSize(&k1);
    assert(returnval == 1);

    printf("Test passed\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189630/discussion-on-question-by-bret-hasel-getting-a-segmentation-fault-when-attemptin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no segmentation fault, but there is an assertion failure, namely the last one in the test case. The reason this happens is because `k1` is `NULL`, which happens because in `KnapsackAdd()` the first if-test hits, and allocates and initializes a new `listitemptr`. However, this is then returned, and that return isn't caught in the test case, meaning that k1 never gets set to the new `listitemptr`. This is both a memory leak and a logic error.

In order to fix it, the easiest would be to make the `knapsack` parameter to a pointer to a pointer and then set it to the newly allocated item in `KnapsackAdd()` to the newly allocated item.